# AWK remove blank lines

Tags: linux, awk

The `/./` is removing blank lines for the first condition `{ print "a"$0 }` only, how would I ensure the script removes blank lines for every condition ?

```
awk -F, '/./ { print "a"$0 } NR!=1 { print "b"$0 } { print "c"$0 } END { print "d"$0 }' MyFile
```

Comment: `awk '/./' MyFile` ? `awk NF` http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-scripting/84923-remove-all-blank-lines-shell-awk.html http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1282604

Comment: I would say it's time to change the accepted answer, except I think @oliv's answer is even better than the one with 25 upvotes so I want to give it time to rise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put following conditions inside the first one, and check them with `if` statements, like this:

```
awk -F, '
    /./ { 
        print "a"$0; 
        if (NR!=1) { print "b"$0 } 
        print "c"$0 
    } 
    END { print "d"$0 }
' MyFile
```

Comment: The chosen answer is too long, there are better one liners such as this one below `awk NF file`

Answer (score 77):

A shorter form of the already proposed answer could be the following:

```
awk NF file
```

Any `awk` script follows the syntax `condition {statement}`. If the statement block is not present, `awk` will print the whole record (line) in case the `condition` is not zero.

`NF` variable in `awk` holds the number of fields in the line. So when the line is non empty, `NF` holds a positive value which trigger the default `awk` action (print the whole line). In case of empty line, `NF` is  zero and the condition is not met, so `awk` does nothing.

Note that you don't even need quote because this 2 letters awk script doesn't contain any space or character that could be interpreted by the shell.

---

or

```
awk '!/^$/' file
```

`^$` is the regex for an empty line. The 2 `/` is needed to let `awk` understand the string is a regex. `!` is the standard negation.

Answer (score 40):

Awk command to remove blank lines from a file:

```
awk 'NF > 0' filename
```

Answer (score 18):

if you want to ignore all blank lines, put this at the beginning of the script

```
/^$/ {next}
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is about `awk` but just to give an alternative with `grep`

### non-empty lines only

```bash
grep -v '^$' foo.txt
```

Will give you all

- non-empty

lines only. Note: it may return lines that have only spaces.

### non-empty and non-blank lines only

```bash
grep -v '^[[:space:]]*$' foo.txt
```

Will give you all

- non-empty **and**
- non-blank (not having only spaces)

lines only. Lines with spaces only are not printed.
You may want to change `[[:space:]]` to `[[:blank:]]` see **references** below.

### references

- [regex - What's the difference between [:space:] and [:blank:]? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15767863/whats-the-difference-between-space-and-blank)

```bash
man grep | less -p '^ *-v'
```

> -v, --invert-match Invert the sense of matching, to select non-matching lines.