# What's the difference between [:space:] and [:blank:]?

Tags: regex, bash, grep

From the [A Brief Introduction to Regular Expressions](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x17046.html)

[:blank:] matches a space or a tab.

[:space:] matches whitespace characters (space and horizontal tab).

To me both definitions are the same and I was wondering if they are really duplicates?

If they are different, what are the differences?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

For the GNU tools the following from `grep.info` applies:

```
[:blank:]

     Blank characters: space and tab.

[:space:]

     Space characters: in the 'C' locale, this is tab, newline,
     vertical tab, form feed, carriage return, and space.
```

You can find the section with this command:

```
info grep 'Regular Expressions' 'Character Classes and Bracket Expressions'
```

Answer (score 4):

A better explanation of what they each match is available here

- http://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html

The biggest difference is that `[:space:]` will also match items like new line characters

Answer (score 0):

A space means to pressing a space bar and tab

A white space means it carries the newline,tab,form feed and carriage return and also space that's all.

Comment: You should provide a link to the official documentation where you got this information otherwise your answer can only be considered as subjective.