# vim search and replace with arithmetic (C pointer)

Tags: c, search, vim, replace

I want to search and replace a pointer

```
char* test
```

however, when I type

```
:%s/char* test/something/g
```

I get

```
E486: Pattern not found: char* test
```

I assume this is due to vim trying to use regex in search.

How can i tackle this issue? Is it possible to replace such text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape star symbol. This should work:

```
:%s/char\* test/something/g
```

Answer (score 1):

```
%s/char[[:blank:]]*[*][[:blank:]]*test/something/g
```

`[[:blank:]]*[*][[:blank:]]*` : To just replace "one" `*` occuring between any number of spaces or tabs. [1]

[1] [What's the difference between [:space:] and [:blank:]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15767863/whats-the-difference-between-space-and-blank)

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution if you want to completely disable regex

```
:%sno/char* test/something
```